# unexpected T_VARIABLE, why is my drop down list not finding the variable I created?

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables, syntax

I am fairly new to PHP. I have created a drop down list which shows a list of ingredients that are either (meat, vegetarian, or vegan). When the user registers to my website, they select which diet they follow and this is inserted in to the database into the column '`dietID`'.

I want the drop down list to automatically ONLY show the meat OR vegetarian OR vegan list of ingredients, DEPENDENT on the users '`dietID`' they registered as.

The error I am getting is

> unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE) ..... on line 42.

(Line 42 is the SELECT statement)

```
require_once("connect.php");
if (!$db_server) {
    die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE dietID="$_SESSION['diet']"";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
    if (!$result)
        die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $str_options .= "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>";
        $str_options .= $row['ingredient'];
        $str_options .= "</option>";
    }
}
```

and the form:

```
<form method="post" action="chefsclaw.php">
Which ingredient are you interesting in finding out the healthy alternatives for?
<br>
<br>
<select name="choice">
<?php
echo $str_options;
?>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Lookup" />
</form>
```

N.B I have created the variables for the dietID on the register page. These variables are:

```
$db_diet = $row['dietID'];

$_SESSION['diet'] = $db_diet;
```

I would appreciate any guidance.

EDIT:
the rest of the form processing code:

```
<?php // connect to database
require_once 'connect.php';
require_once 'checklog.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
$str_message = $message = $str_comments = $output = "";
if (!$db_server) {
    die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    // this tests if look up form has an input
    if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Lookup") { // set to value of your submit
        if (isset($_POST['choice'])) { //Capture form data, if anything was submitted
            $choice = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['choice']);
            $query  = "SELECT ingredient, alternative, dietID FROM ingredients WHERE ID=$choice";
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); // query the database
            $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

            if (!$result)
                die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server) . $query);

            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // if there are any rows, print out the contents
                $output = 'The healthy alternatives for ' . $row['ingredient'] . ' could be ' . $row['alternative'] . ' which would suit a ' . $row['dietID'] . ' based diet. ';

            } else {
                $output = 'The ingredient selected was not found in the database';
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else {
            $output = 'No ingredient was selected';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `WHERE dietID='".$_SESSION['diet']."'";` there. Now I can go eat.

Comment: i see quotes with in quotes

Comment: @Fred-ii- great thank you! that sorted that error, but now the drop down list is empty!

Comment: You do string concatenation in PHP using a period, similar to @Fred-ii- 's answer

Comment: @Dagon [*"You're seeing stars"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oALxLNOhI6I)

Comment: question is; did you start the session? and using a form with nothing to fetch from. You're also not echoing `$str_options`. I think that's the *clincher* here ;-) supper's in 5 mins. so... I won't be able to help out when that happens ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i added start session and it didn't change anything. The form does echo $str_options. I think it is a problem with my variables, because as a test I just tried to echo my dietID variable and it was empty

Comment: ask the guy below then, who put in an answer for what I already said here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha, not helpful tho :(

Comment: far as I can tell, your query's outside your form tags and again; I don't know why you're using a form and without POST arrays. I can't quite make out what you're trying to do here; a search?

Comment: its a search to bring back a list of ingredients, it isn't submitting any data. The drop down list works if I define the dietID as 'vegan' in the where clause. but i want the dietID to be the dietID of that logged in user

Comment: @Fred-ii- now i know why youre confused, forgot to add the processing code, now added as an edit. apologies

Comment: @Fred-ii- are you able to see any errors that could be causing me problems, now that i've added the processing code? :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- ignore that! it's all working now. I think it had something to do with my variables not being written correctly! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with quotes in quotes, try this.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE dietID='".$_SESSION['diet']."'";
```

Comment: My bad, missed your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of commentor Fred -ii- i needed to change my `SELECT` statement to the following

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE dietID='".$_SESSION['diet']."'";
```

I also then needed to change my SESSION variable to

```
$_SESSION['diet'] = $dietopt;
```

in order to 'grab' the correct data submitted initially by the radio button on my register form (where the user submits their ' dietID '.)

**Many thanks for all help.**